# Is it possible to define different tolerances in a ODE system using scipy

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I am solving a system of 2 coupled differential equations using the 'DOP853' solver of
scipy.integrate.solve_ivp. I can not find a way to put different values of absolute tolerance (atol) for the difference equations. Is it possible in some way?
Thanks for help!

Comment: Did you consult the documentation? At least in scipy 1.1.0, `rtol` and `atol` can also be "array-like", for exactly the reason you state. Did this fail for the  RK method you used?

Comment: If you want to take this adaptation out of the hands of the solver, you can also include the corresponding scales into the ODE function. If `f(t,u)` is the original function, and `scales` the array of the typical sizes of the state components, then define `scaled_u0 = u0/scales` and `scaled_f = lambda t,u: f(t,u*scales)/scales`. Re-scale finally the output.